# How to scale image in cms Magento

Tags: image, magento, content-management-system, resize

When the admin adds an image to a cms page in Magento, and then resize the image:
then the image at the frontend retains its original size, but scaled.

Is there any solution to save the image in smaller size when the page is saved?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way this will happen with any default magento. However, you could put together a module that will observe your cms page saved data. Take for instance this event:

```
cms_page_prepare_save
```

with parameters:

```
array(’page’ ⇒ $model, ‘request’ ⇒ $this→getRequest())
```

You can create the module starting with only 3 files:

/app/etc/Electricjesus_Cms.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Electricjesus_Cms>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Electricjesus_Cms>
    </modules>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Electricjesus/Cms/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Electricjesus_Cms>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Electricjesus_Cms>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <cms>
                <class>Electricjesus_Cms_Model</class>
            </cms>
        </models>
        <events>
            <cms_page_prepare_save>
                <observers>
                    <prepareSave>
                        <class>cms/observer</class>
                        <method>prepareSave</method>
                    </prepareSave>
                </observers>
            </cms_page_prepare_save>
        </events>        
    </global>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Electricjesus/Cms/Model/Observer.php:

```
<?php
class Electricjesus_Cms_Model_Observer {
    function prepareSave ( $observer ) {
       $request = $observer->getRequest();
       $params = $request->getParams();
       // scan the request and params for stuff related with the images.. 
       // find out scaling and pass into a good resizer like TimThumb or
       // Zend_Filter_ImageSize etc.
    }
}
```

While the above answer is not complete, this is a good place to start. I'll try and develop a complete solution whenever I have more time on it.

**Alternative method:**

Since I mentioned [TimThumb](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/08/timthumb/) above, you can also deploy that at your magento root and start adding your images via HTML editor instead of the usual WYSIWYG editor. If installing thumb.php on your website root directory, you can use it like so:

```
<img src="/thumb.php?src=images/image.jpg&w=100&h=50" alt="Hey" />
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanx. I shall check this out.